# The red underline in VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, editor, fault

I'm beginner and I have a problem in the lastest VS code. I just download VS code and I run perfectly. But I don't understand why my VS code doesn't have the red underline when I code incorrectly. Can you show me how to make VS code have the red underline when I code incorrectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Intellisense is setup in your c_cpp_properties.json. The documentation explains how it all works here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_cc-configurations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_cc-configurations)

Answer (score -1):

Go to settings and search for "error squiggles", there are two options user and workspace. Choose workspace and change the setting of "error squiggles" to enabled.

Comment: I have done what you said but nothing changes. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q91qDL3Jo329j7cpz3NG2l3HaviDEagB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you enabled it under the workspace tab? Below the search bar there are two tabs user and workspace you need to enable it under workspace tab.

Comment: My VS code doesn't have workspace near tab user.